# Is static wrapping of complex function calls bad practice?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a Factory Method that is relatively complex to call:

```
DatabaseAccessFactory.Instance.GetDatabaseAccess().GetUserData(userId) 
DatabaseAccessFactory.Instance.GetDatabaseAccess().InsertData(dataStr1,dataStr2);
```

To avoid having to call this large querys i wrant to wrap these calls in a static class:

```
public static class SQL
{
    public static User GetUserData(int userId)
    {
        return DatabaseAccessFactory.Instance.
            GetDatabaseAccess().GetUserData(userId);
    }
    public static void InsertData(String dataStr1, String dataStr2)
    {
        DatabaseAccessFactory.Instance.
            GetDatabaseAccess().InsertData(dataStr1,dataStr2);
    }
}
```

So that i could simply call:

```
SQL.GetUserData(userId) 
SQL.InsertData(dataStr1,dataStr2);
```

Is this considered bad practice?

**Edit:**
Fixed Source

Comment: In my opinion it is, since it only makes it harder to see what's going on there. I'd be more concerned about why are you calling `GetDatabaseAccess()` twice, instead of storing it as a variable/member somewhere. The purpose of a factory pattern is not to create a new object every time you want to call its function..

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, C# has namespaces, but I fail to see how they would help here.

Comment: your SQL-class does not provide a method called GetDatabaseAccess, you may simply call SQL.GetUserData(userID).

Comment: "The purpose of a factory pattern is not to create a new object every time you want to call its function." The factory creates the Database objects only once. If is exits it returns the existing databaseaccess object

Comment: With those static what you are doing is simply wrapping methods. Wrapping methods have been existing for ages. If that code would have been called from a DLL you would have done the same. As long as the class is a Singleton i don't see a single problem with using wrapper methods. And BTW these kind of methods is the way you would make them is you implement in a buisness logic layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution only removes the `Instance` part out of the method call, a better alternative would be to completely remove the nested dot-notation e.g.

```
public static class SQL
{
    static IDatabase db = DatabaseAccessFactory.Instance.GetDatabaseAccess();

    public static User GetUserData(int userId)
    {
        return db.GetUserData(userId);
    }

    public static void InsertData(String dataStr1, String dataStr2)
    {
        db.InsertData(dataStr1, dataStr2);
    }
}
```

That way your usage would be

```
SQL.GetUserData(userId);
SQL.InsertData(dataStr1, dataStr2);
```

However, just be wary how you intend on using this code, sharing database connections *application-wide* can be troublesome, especially in a multi-threaded environment.